# Checkbox on a meta box using CMB2 Plugin

Tags: metabox, oembed

I have ***ADDED*** a meta box for Video using oembed by the help of CMB2 plugin.
here is the code →

```
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => ('oEmbed'),
    'desc' => 'Enter a youtube, twitter, or instagram URL. Supports services listed at <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds">http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds</a>.',
    'id'   => $prefix . 'video_id',
    'type' => 'oembed',
    ) );
```

and to print this in the theme. I am ***echoing*** it like this →

```
<?php
    $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_the_video_id', 1 ) );
    echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
?>
```

But what I want is that in the above meta box(***using oembed***) there should be a ***checkbox***.

and I should be an able to put a condition →

```
If (checkbox==true) {
      <?php
          $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_the_video_id', 1 ) );
          echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
    ?>
{

$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'             => 'Select Video or Image',
    'desc'             => 'Select an option',
    'id'               => $prefix . 'image_or_video',
    'type'             => 'select',
    'show_option_none' => true,
    'default'          => 'custom',
    'options'          => array(
        'standard' => __( 'Option One', 'cmb2' ),
        'custom'   => __( 'Option Two', 'cmb2' ),
        'none'     => __( 'Option Three', 'cmb2' ),
    ),
) );
```

Please help me to achieve this→

```
If Option chosen is Option 2 {
Execute some PHP code
}
```

## MY QUESTION

How could I write this → If ***Option chosen*** is Option 2 in terms of programming?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the CMB2 plugin, but it's worth mentioning that WordPress has a built-in function for checking the value of a checkbox. You can use [`checked();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) for the second part of your code.

Comment: CMB2 is actually a library that makes it easy to write meta's https://getflywheel.com/layout/how-to-create-custom-meta-boxes-with-cmb2/

Comment: Further details can be found here → https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage

Comment: I have this kind of situation Now → [Situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446980/how-to-select-the-options-condition)

Comment: I have updated the question can you Please help me Now.

Comment: Is this your answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446980/how-to-select-the-options-condition/45452029#45452029

Comment: Yes, Yes! Sir!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get it right, then you just need to get that value from post meta, and make condition.

```
$image_or_video = get_post_meta($post_id, $prefix . 'image_or_video', true);

// Option 2 is selected
if( 'custom' === $image_or_video ){
 //Then execute some PHP code
}
```

Comment: Let me Try this and update you.

Comment: Oh, my friend its working. you are such a fantastic person. This is a good question. Please also upvote me.